# Directions map not centering/zooming properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

**UPDATE:** I have a static solution working right now, but I'd still like to see if it can be improved upon. All of the code is the same aside from the on click event for switching views.

```
$(document).on('click', '.mobile-toggle a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        var target = $(this).attr("data-target");

        $("#results > div, .mobile-toggle a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#" + target).addClass("active");
    }

    var center = dmap.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(dmap, 'resize');
    dmap.setCenter(center);
    dmap.setZoom(12);
});
```

This gets the map centered properly, which is good. The zoom is also fine, but it doesn't always fit the route. Sometimes the route is too big to fit, and other times the map should probably be zoomed in a little bit more. Is there any way to determine the zoom value that should be used based on the route? I'm fairly certain this is generally supposed to happen on its own, but that doesn't seem to be the case this time around.

Original post below.

---

I've read a bunch of questions/answers about this, but none of the provided answers seem to do what I'm looking for. I'll try to explain this the best I can.

I'm currently writing a store locator. On desktop, everything looks fine. Mobile is where I run into difficulty because of some changing views (showing/hiding divs). From what I've read, it looks like a lot of people run into a problem where the map is created in a hidden div and then it's displayed incorrectly (e.g. the map only occupies the top left area of the container) when the div is shown.

The layout of the store locator is as follows - after you search for a location, you see a list view of all the results. When you click the 'map view' tab up top, you see a Google maps view with all of the nearby stores on it. This works fine. If you select a store and click 'get directions' from the list view, you see a list view of the directions to get to that store. Likewise, if you select a store and click 'get directions' while in map view, you see a map of the directions. That works fine in both scenarios.

The issue is when I am in a list view, click to get directions, and then switch over from the list view of directions to the map view. The map gets drawn with the correct route and it fills the div just like it should - however, the route is in the top left of the map, and the map itself is zoomed way out. For example, if the route is in the Philadelphia area, the map is so zoomed out that its center is generally around Bermuda. And it's roughly the same spot in Bermuda every time.

Here's the relevant code for the button press between list and map views.

```
$(document).on('click', '.mobile-toggle a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!(this).hasClass("active")) {
        var target = $(this).attr("data-target");

        $("#results > div, .mobile-toggle a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#" + target).addClass("active");
    }
    google.maps.event.trigger(dmap, 'resize');
}
```

`dmap` is a global variable containing the directions map, and the map itself has these two listeners assigned to it when it is created.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(dmap, 'idle', function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(dmap, 'resize');
    dmapCenter = dmap.getCenter();
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function () {
    dmap.setCenter(dmapCenter);
});
```

This redraws the map and makes sure the center stays the same while the window is resized, but the map itself still isn't focused on the route from location A to location B. I feel like the solution can't be too far from what I've already tried (based on what I've read), but I can't seem to get this working.

Sorry about the wall of text. If there's any other code you think would help potentially answer the question, please let me know. Thanks!

EDIT: As requested, here's the full code that draws the map.

```
function calcRoute(start, dest) {
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('directions-map'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions'));

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: dest,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });

    dmap = map;
    dmapCenter = map.getCenter();

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        dmapCenter = map.getCenter();
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function () {
        map.setCenter(dmapCenter);
    });
}
```

`lat` and `lng` are global variables with the latitude and longitude of the search location.

Comment: You should look into [fitBounds()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) , first method on this linked page, and also set the zoom on the map when you resize it.

Comment: Can you include the code you use to draw the directions on the map?

Comment: @XionDark Sure. I just added it to the question.

Comment: @Jack is the `div` you use for the map, on which you display the near by store locations (let's call it "Store Map" or `smap`), the same `div` you use for the map that has the directions drawn on it (let's call it "Direction Map" or `dmap`)?

Comment: @XionDark No - the two maps are on two separate divs. The store map seems to be working fine in all use cases. The directions maps works properly aside from the one case I mentioned above where the user (viewing the list of stores) clicks 'get directions' and then switches over to 'map view.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow you are using (IMHO) seems a little odd to me (IMHO), mainly of your choice to initialize a map instance every time you calculate the directions.

I don't know how much this will help since I haven't been able to test it on a mobile device, but below is code to make a google map, render directions between two points, and maintain the map center after the map is resized (test resize by running snippet in full page than resizing the browser window).

```js
var DMAP,
    DMAP_RENDERER,
    DIRECTIONS_SERVICE;

/*
 Run only once when your page loads to ready global components
 for any future direction calls.
 */
function initializeDirectionsFeature(){
    //set up directions map
    var dmapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.8282, -98.5795) //USA center
    };
    DMAP = new google.maps.Map( $("#map").get(0), dmapOptions);
    
    //set up renderer for directions map
    var rendererOptions = {
        map: DMAP,
        panel: $("#directions").get(0)
    };
    DMAP_RENDERER = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    
    //Initialize the directions service
    DIRECTIONS_SERVICE = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    
    //Trigger map redraw when dom element is resized
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(DMAP, 'resize');
    });
    
    //Preserve map perspective when after resize
    google.maps.event.addListener(DMAP, 'resize', function () {
        var center = DMAP.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(DMAP, 'center_changed', function () {
            DMAP.setCenter( center );
        });
    });
}

/*
 Gets and renders the directions between params.
 Params 'from' and 'to' can be either LatLng or
 a String that will be geocoded. Param 'renderer'
 is the `google.maps.DirectionsRenderer` to use.
 */
function calcDirections(from, to, renderer){
    var request = {
        origin: from,
        destination: to,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    DIRECTIONS_SERVICE.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            renderer.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}

//for Snippet, actuall run google maps initialize function
initializeDirectionsFeature();

//For Snippet example
$("#query").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    calcDirections(e.target.from.value, e.target.to.value, DMAP_RENDERER)
});
```

```css
/* just for Snippet, gmap element just needs a height */
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 98%;
  height: 98%;
  min-height: 500px;
}
#map, #directions {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}
.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
<form id="query">
    <div class="inline-block">
        <label for="from">From:</label>
        <input id="from" name="from" value="New York, NY"/>
    </div>
    <div class="inline-block">
        <label for="to">To:</label>
        <input id="to" name="to" value="Philadelphia, PA"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="directions">Directions:</div>
```

Comment: It didn't even occur to me that I was creating a new map instance every time. Thanks so much for the help! I really appreciate it.